# Remove iOS UISearchBar Animation

Tags: ios, iphone, uisearchbar, uisearchbardelegate

The animation a search bar in iOS runs when you select it is very slow on the iPhone 4s (which I want to support). Is there any way to remove that animation?

Comment: just use a uitextfield, it works the same way, you just need to add buttons around it using its left and right views

Comment: How would you implement a searchBarDelegate with a text field?